# Issues committing files to Github from XCode : warning: unable to access '/Users/alexandra/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied

Tags: xcode, git, commit

> warning: unable to access '/Users/alexandra/.config/git/ignore':
>   Permission denied

I've followed a few other open forums with the same issue but still not resolved, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Simply follow the below steps. Hope your issue will get resolved.

1. Go to project folder from finder
2. Right-click -> Choose Folder Action Setup
3. Select "Enable Folder Actions"

Enjoy!!!